# Is it possible to use inheritance to implement an ECS in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, entity

I'm trying to architect a game I'm writing in C++ as an Entity/Component system (the basic idea being I would have a set of "Entity" classes representing different kinds of  data and a set of "Component" classes representing various behaviors a given entity could have). I wanted to implement it using virtual base classes for the components. For instance, I could have a `Character` entity:

```
class Character {
public:
    int armor;
    int health;
    std::string name;
};
```

as well as a `Fighter` component representing something that can use melee weapons:

```
class Fighter {
public:
    int damage;
    virtual Direction attack() = 0;
}
```

and a `Mage` component representing something that can cast spells

```
class Mage {
public:
    std::vector<Spell> spellList;
    virtual Spell cast() = 0;
}
```

Using multiple inheritance to use these, I'd have

```
class ElvenMage : Character, Mage {
public:
    ElvenMage() {
        this->armor = 0;
        this->health = 10;
        this->name = "elven mage";
        this->spellList = ...;
    }
    virtual Spell cast() {
        // some AI logic to figure out which spell to cast
    }
};
```

and

```
class Player : Character, Fighter, Mage {
public:
    Player() {
        this->armor = 5;
        this->health = 20;
        this->name = "Player";
    }
    virtual Direction attack() {
        // some logic to handle player melee input
    }
    virtual Spell cast() {
        // some logic to handle player spell casting input
    }
};
```

To keep track of all current characters on the map I could do something like

```
class Engine {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Character>> characters;
```

I have to store them directly as `Characters` (not as `Fighters` or `Mages`), yet I would need to process fighters and mages separately (for instance, looping through all `Characters` and if they can cast a spell they do so otherwise they attack with a melee weapon). In the actual game logic, how would I distinguish between an instance of `Character` that also implements `Mage` vs. an instance of `Character` that also implements `Fighter`?

Is there an easy way to do what I am trying to, or should I completely rethink my design?

(note: this isn't actual code; in the real world I'd actually use a factory or something to create elves or whatever instead of trying to put all the information in the constructor, and I'd probably separate the logic differently, but it illustrates the problem I'm having).

Comment: ECS is to literally not have inheritance, if that's what you're aiming for, read ECS again. It is typical for a game engine to require checking for the type of an object, so you will have something like `dynamic_cast<Mage*>(&someCharachter)` in your current design, as well as making `Character` polymorphic.

Comment: @PasserBy I know its supposed to avoid complex inheritance hierarchies but the concept of "all `Character`s that are `Mage`s can `cast`" basically seems identical to java's `interface` or c++'s virtual class paradigms. Also I know I would have to dynamic cast, my problem was how would I know just given a `Character` instance which components it implements to know what to cast

Comment: @Raghav Malik In this specific case they are very similar. The problem isn't about calling one method on one object, but how to handle many thousands of objects with potentially hundreds of components each. In this case, they are very different. The simplest way to implement a component system is to make a `GameObject` class and give it a pointer to each possible component type. If you want all mages, just iterate over all objects and grab those which have a non null pointer to a `MageComponent`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in your Engine:

Each character would override the pure virtual accept method of the `Character` class.

```
class Engine;
class Spell {};
class Direction {};

class Character {
 public:
  virtual void accept(Engine& engine) = 0;
};

class Fighter {
 public:
  virtual Direction attack() = 0;
};

class Mage {
 public:
  virtual Spell cast() = 0;
};
```

Inheriting `Character` in `Mage` and `Fighter` would include less boilerplate code. If you want to stick to your form of inheritance, you need to provide an overload of the `accept` method in each character, which just calls the `visit` function of the `Engine`:

```
class ElvenMage : public Character, Mage {
 public:
  ElvenMage() {}
  virtual Spell cast() {
    std::cout << "Casting from ElvenMage"
              << "\n";
    return Spell{};
  }

  void accept(Engine& visitor) override { visitor.visit(*this); }
};

class Player : public Character, Fighter, Mage {
 public:
  Player() {}
  virtual Direction attack() {
    std::cout << "Attacking from Player"
              << "\n";
    return Direction{};
  }

  virtual Spell cast() {
    std::cout << "Casting from Player"
              << "\n";
    return Spell{};
  }

  void accept(Engine& visitor) override { 
    // cast to Player if it should attack instead of casting
    visitor.visit(static_cast<Mage&>(*this)); 
  }
};
```

The `visit` method is where the magic happens:

```
class Engine {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Character>> characters;
  void do_stuff_with_spell(Spell spell) {
    // ...
  }
  void do_stuff_with_attack(Direction direction) {
    // ...
  }

 public:
  void visit(Mage& mage) { do_stuff_with_spell(mage.cast()); }
  void visit(Player& player) { do_stuff_with_attack(player.attack()); }

};
```

Note, that I have a circular dependency in the code above, which should be resolved when splitting up the declarations and definitions.